# Quintic diophantine equation $x^5+y^5=7z^5$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Are there any non-zero integer solutions to the equation $x^5+y^5=7z^5$? I am unsure how to approach this.

Comment: it is homogeneous, you may demand $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1.$ Then try $\pmod {11},$ that may be enough.

Comment: @WillJagy, how did you know that $11$ would work?

Comment: @lhf, the thing is restrictive because 5 divides 11-1; the fifth power map is five to one in geeral, values $0,1,-1.$ The bad news is that this does not suffice to finish the question. I would like to know the source of the question. ...We could have $$  x^5 \equiv 1, \; \; y^5 \equiv -1, \; \; z^5 \equiv 0 \pmod {11} $$

Comment: Yes I had already observed that small congruences don't rule out much. (There are also many candidates mod 31 and 41 it appears.) On the other hand, a computer search rules out solutions with $\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)<10^4$

Answer (score 1):

This question has been solved on Mathoverflow.

[Solution by Michael Stoll](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224232/rational-points-on-the-quintic-circle-x5-y5-7)

The integer points are given by $(x,-x,0)$ for $x\in \mathbb Z$.

The trick is to reduce the equation to a form that has been studied more extensively. For any solution $(x,y,z)$ to the equation with $z\not=0$, let $X=-xy/z^2$ and $Y=\frac{x^5}{z^5}-\frac{7}{2}$. Then $Y^2-\frac{49}{4}=X^5$, which is a [hyperelliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_curve), and there are techniques for finding all rational solutions to such an equation.